# PHP: как вывести условие для array_filter() за пределы функции?

Tags: php, массивы

У нас есть массив:

```html
$array = [
  [
    'id' => '1',
    'title' => 'Страница 1',
    'price' => '100'
  ],
  [
    'id' => '2',
    'title' => 'Страница 2',
    'price' => '200'
  ],
  [
    'id' => '3',
    'title' => 'Страница 3',
    'price' => '300'
  ]
];
```

Вот фильтрация этого массива:

```html
$array = array_filter($array, function ($array) {
  return $array['price'] > 100 && $array['title'] != 'Страница 3';
});
```

Как вывести условие return за пределы функции, чтобы каждый раз ее не вызывать, а только вставлять условие?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `array_filter` вызывает ваш коллбэк для каждого элемента, так что *"чтобы каждый раз ее не вызывать"* не получится никак.

Comment: разве что вы хотите применить это сравнение в нескольких местах, тогда вынесите `$filter = function($array){...}` в переменную и используйте потом как `array_filter($data, $filter)`

Comment: В этом и проблема, я сейчас делаю массив из разных условий и потом с помощью foreach прохожу по каждому из условий. Ну там тоже много проблем, потому что знак сравнения из переменной не достанешь, поэтому приходится писать внутри функции свой switch / case, ну и прочие проблемы...

Comment: сделайте массива анонимных функций.

Comment: @RUDremin вы бы показали задачу полностью, было бы проще что-то советовать. Сейчас из текста вопроса вообще непонятно, что куда вы хотите вынести

Comment: @splash58 у него массив условий для фильтрации есть. В случае, когда `['price' => 100, 'title' => 'xxx']`, можно использовать обычные равенства при сравнении и все просто. но когда надо сравнивать `>=` например, или нужно не `AND` условие, то код прилично усложняется.

Comment: Все верно, array_filter, по всей видимости, для этой задачи не подходит. Нужно изобретать велосипед, как-то фильтровать массив другим способом.

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, что правильно понял ваш вопрос, если что подправите.

1. Создадим класс, который будет содержать все наши условия.

   ```
   class MyFilter {

        private $filters = [];

        public function addFilter(callable $filter) {
            $this->filters[] = $filter;
        }
        /**
         * @param array $data
         * Возвращаем true если для $data справедливо хотябы одно условие
        */
        public function filter(array $data) {
            foreach ($this->filters as $filter) {
                if($filter($data)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
   }
   ```
2. Создаем экземпляр нашего класса и добавим два фильтра

   ```
   $myFilter = new MyFilter();

   $myFilter->addFilter(function ($data) {
       return $data['price'] > 100 && $data['title'] != 'Страница 3';
   });
   $myFilter->addFilter(function ($data) {
       return $data['id'] == 3 && $data['price'] == 300;
   });
   ```
3. Сама фильтрация

   ```
   $array = [
    [
        'id' => '1',
        'title' => 'Страница 1',
        'price' => '100'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '2',
        'title' => 'Страница 2',
        'price' => '200'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '3',
        'title' => 'Страница 3',
        'price' => '300'
    ]
   ];

   $filterate = array_filter($array, function ($data) use ($myFilter) {
      return $myFilter->filter($data);
   });

   print_r($filterate);

   /* ВЫВОД
   Array
   (
       [1] => Array
           (
               [id] => 2
               [title] => Страница 2
               [price] => 200
           )

       [2] => Array
           (
               [id] => 3
               [title] => Страница 3
               [price] => 300
           )

   )
   */
   ```

Comment: Нет, тут слишком много кода. Смысл в том, чтобы исполнять в return содержание переменной, предположим $string = '(id == 1 || id == 2) && price > 100', находящуюся за пределами функции array_filter(). Но передавать в переменной операторы сравнения не получится. То есть передать по идее можно только id или price, а сравнивать уже нужно непосредственно в return.